# PHP calling a class method with class name as variable string

Tags: php, class

I have a class from which I want to call a function, but the instantiated class variable is taken from a string.

```
class Myclass
{
 public function myFunction($param1,$param2) {
  return 'blah';
 }
}
```

I am trying the following but it doesn't work. Errors from log file below.

```
$myclass='myclass';
${$myclass}=new ucfirst($myclass);
$args=array($stringvar,1);
$retval=call_user_func_array(array(${$myclass}, 'myFunction'), $args);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Errors :

```
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in file.php on line 100
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: myclass in file.php on line 134
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function myFunction() on a non-object in file.php on line 134
```

Comment: Why are you doing this... such a mess :D

Comment: Any help welcome. I've explained a bit more below.

Comment: I appreciate that you are after an answer to the problem you have. May i ask, what was the original problem that you were trying to solve? I keep remembering this 'maxim': it is hard to remember, when you are up to your a*s* in crocodiles, that the original intention was to drain the swamp. Your code, by its nature, will be hard to maintain and change in the future.

Comment: @RyanVincent my man, this is what I meant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it a bit with the extra ${} bracketing on the class reference.

```
$myclass='myCLaSs';
$myObject = new $myclass();
$retval = $myObject->myFunction($stringvar, 1);
```

Or if you need to use call_user_func_array:

```
$args=array($stringvar,1);
$retval=call_user_func_array(array($myObject, 'myFunction'), $args);
```

When you use the ${} bracketing, you are referencing variables by a variable name. For example:

```
$myVariable = "A";
$aVariableThatIsHoldingAVariableName = "myVariable";
echo ${$aVariableThatIsHoldingAVariableName}; // outputs "A".
```

Applying this to your code shows the following logic happening:

Set the variable `$myclass` equal to the string 'myclass'

```
$myclass='myclass';
```

Set the variable `${$myclass}`:

This gets the value of the variable `$myclass` ('myclass') and uses that as the variable name. In other words, the following variable name resolution happens: `${$myclass}` => `${'myclass'}` => `$myclass`.

So this line sets `$myclass` to a `new Myclass();` object:

```
${$myclass}=new ucfirst($myclass);
```

The first parameter to `call_user_func_array` is a `callable` (See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). The callback it looks like you are trying to reference here is Type 3: `array($object, $method)`. But the same variable resolution happens. Now, `${$myclass}` is going to resolve differently, because the value of `$myclass` is a Myclass Object. Variable names have to be strings, not objects (obviously), so `${Myclass Object}` is totally invalid.

```
$args=array($stringvar,1);
$retval=call_user_func_array(array(${$myclass}, 'myFunction'), $args);
```

But since $myclass at that point is an object already, you can just do the following (as mentioned initially above):

```
$retval=call_user_func_array(array($myclass, 'myFunction'), $args);
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the ${$myclass} is necessary because I'm taking the class name as a string from a DB table.

Comment: In the example I've included, $myclass is a string. You can reference it directly in the new () call.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an example of how the ${} bracketing syntax works.

Comment: Let's say that I have an array from which I get the various class names which I want to instantiate. Whenever I want to reference these, I have to get the string (myclass, myclass1, myclassn). Am I too tired to understand how to apply this or should I look for a way to store the objects somewhere ?

Comment: Too tired is my bet :) If you dont want to create an object and just want to call the functions on the class (maybe they are static for example), you can pass the string directly in as the class name to the `callback` parameter for `call_user_func_array`, e.g., with `$myclass` being the variable with the class name, `call_user_func_array($myclass, 'myFunction'), $args)`. Copy and paste this code and your class definition in to a test script and play around with it, might help shake the cobwebs off :)

Comment: Thanks ;) But could you help me to see what's wrong with the code I posted ? I mean with the call_user_func_array(array(${$myclass}, 'myFunction'), $args); part ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I have been doing. I have edited the original post with details about how the variable resolution of the `${}` syntax happens and why it is failing for you.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I didn't see the update when I posted. After some sleep I was able to see the point here :) And I typed some variable wrong somewhere in the code before this... Thanks again ;)